# Display Footer Shortcode Different for Logged In Users

Tags: conditional-tags, conditional-content

I have a shortcode that displays a block of content.  Is there a way I can display different HTML depending on if the user is logged in or not?  Below is what I have so far.

```
function footer_shortcode(){
    $siteURL = site_url();
    $logoutURL = wp_logout_url(home_url());

    echo '
        <div class="signin_container"> 
            <h4 class="signin_footer_head">Log In To My Account</h4>
            <a href="'.$siteURL.'/login/">Log In</a>
            <a href="'.$siteURL.'/register/">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
    ';  
}

add_shortcode('footerShortcode', 'footer_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional tag to check if the user is logged in.  Conditionals are very common in W, I would suggest you give [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) a read.

Here is an example.

```
function footer_shortcode(){
    if (is_user_logged_in()){
        echo '
            // Logged In Content
        ';
    }else{
        echo '
            // Logged Out Content
        ';
    }       
}

add_shortcode('footerShortcode', 'footer_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `is_user_logged_in()`

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Example:

```
function footer_shortcode(){
    $siteURL = site_url();
    $logoutURL = wp_logout_url(home_url());

   if(is_user_logged_in()) { // user is logged in
      echo '
        <div class="signin_container"> 
            <h4 class="signin_footer_head">Account Info</h4>
        </div>
    '; 
   }

   else { //user is not logged in
      echo '
        <div class="signin_container"> 
            <h4 class="signin_footer_head">Log In To My Account</h4>
            <a href="'.$siteURL.'/login/">Log In</a>
            <a href="'.$siteURL.'/register/">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
    '; 
   } 
}

add_shortcode('footerShortcode', 'footer_shortcode');
```

Edit: I see RiddleMeThis beat me to the punch

Comment: Quick Draw for the win : )